# EMDK barcode scanning is not working after disable Enable instant run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy (default enabled) option

Tags: android, motorola-emdk

I want to generate signed apk for emdk scanning for zebra scanner device. When I'm trying to generate apk after disable Enable instant run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy (default enabled) option from instant run. The scanning is not working and it throws below exception,

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=314984880
at com.symbol.emdk.EMDKManager.getInstance(EMDKManager.java:221)
at com.expeditors.eiscanning.scan.emdk.EMDKWrapper$EMDKImplementationWrapper.onOpened(EMDKWrapper.java:151)
at com.symbol.emdk.EMDKServiceConnection.notifyonConnected(EMDKServiceConnection.java:124)
at com.symbol.emdk.EMDKServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(EMDKServiceConnection.java:104)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1208)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1225)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

while executing the below line,

```
BarcodeManager   barcodeManager = (BarcodeManager) emdkManager.getInstance(EMDKManager.FEATURE_TYPE.BARCODE);
```

Could you please suggest me any idea to do this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this also occur with the sample app? https://github.com/Zebra/samples-emdkforandroid-6_6/tree/BarcodeSample1

Comment: @DarrynCampbell yes

Comment: Strange.  What device is this?  Also, can you try a clean build?

Comment: @DarrynCampbell yes I have cleaned my build and I'm having Zebra scanner model number is TC8000. And Just for clarification In this above sample I have replace compile version as compileSdkVersion 23 instead of compileSdkVersion 'Zebra Technologies Corp:EMDK APIs:23' and added emdk jar. Because of this I'm having this problem?

Comment: Thanks, did you add the jar file as provided?  You will get an error if you add it as compile.  Here is the gradle line from one of my projects: https://github.com/darryncampbell/WakeLock_WifiLock_Exerciser/blob/master/WakeLock_WifiLock_Exerciser/app/build.gradle#L33

Comment: @DarrynCampbell no my gradle for adding emdk jar is looks like this,  compile files('libs/com.symbol.emdk.jar')

Comment: You need to add the jar file as provided, then it should work

Comment: @DarrynCampbell could you please provide me some like to do that?

Comment: I already did... that was what the link to my gradle project was.

Comment: @DarrynCampbell okay thank u